# iOS Safe Area in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

Not a frequent iOS dev here, just saw this and had me curious enough to stick it on SO. I created two storyboards, and the view controllers in one of them show the safe area colored with the child view's bg color:

[image: Full Background Color]

And the other storyboard with view controllers all that have what I believe to be the same settings show the safe area does not:

[image]

No matter it seems, as running the app reveals the safe area is getting colored, just had me wondering if it is an Xcode quirk or maybe there is something I'm missing.

Thanks!

Comment: It's because, the first controller has no navigationController, the second one has it.

Comment: Both of the storyboards here start with a Navigation Controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first screenshot, your navigation controller has no Tab Bar displayed. However, it is visible on the second screenshot.

You can toggle the tab bar's visibility in the **Attributes inspector** (the icon with three horizontal lines and circles on the right side of the screen) by changing the **Top Bar** setting.

[image: Screenshot of the Attributes inspector with the Top Bar setting visible]

Possible values and their meanings:

- **None:** the top bar won't be visible.
- **Inferred:** the top bar will mimic the default setting (which will be inferred from the parent navigation controller in this case)
- **Other values:** the top bar will have the explicitly selected style.

[image: Possible values of the Top Bar setting]

Comment: Thanks! Wasn't exactly the cause in this case, but pointed me to where the difference was - the associated Navigation Controller has a checkbox for Shows Navigation Bar in its Attributes Inspector that was checked in the second screenshot but not in the first.